# Why isn't my CSV being written without any data?

Tags: javascript, json, node.js, csv

I'm writing a function which takes in the results of a web scrape that I've performed on a tshirt website.

Each tshirt, has been stored as an object, with a title, price, imgUrl, URL and time. Each of these objects is stored in an array, holding all the tshirts.

In this function, I first convert the array to a JSON string. I console log this, just to check this is being done correctly.

I then create the folder if it doesn't already exist called data.

I list the fields I want for the CSV.

I then write the file by passing in my data (JSON string), the file path, and set it to overwrite.

Right now, when I call the function, it does all it's required to, except, when I open up the CSV file, the columns are titled correctly, yet the table is completely empty.

Any ideas? I'd really appreciate your input, thank you!

Code is below:

```
var json2csv = require('json2csv');
var fs = require('fs');

function convertJson2Csv(){

//The scraper should generate a folder called `data` if it doesn’t exist.
var dir ='./data';

if(!fs.existsSync(dir)){
    fs.mkdirSync(dir);
};

var tshirtArray = [ { 
    Title: 'Mike the Frog Shirt, Orange',
    Price: '$25',
    ImageURL: 'img/shirts/shirt-108.jpg',
    URL: 'http://shirts4mike.com/shirt.php?id=105',
    Date: 'September 23rd 2016, 12:28:49 am' 
},{ 
    Title: 'Logo Shirt, Teal',
    Price: '$20',
    ImageURL: 'img/shirts/shirt-107.jpg',
    URL: 'http://shirts4mike.com/shirt.php?id=105',
    Date: 'September 23rd 2016, 12:28:49 am' 
},{ 
    Title: 'Logo Shirt, Gray',
    Price: '$20',
    ImageURL: 'img/shirts/shirt-106.jpg',
    URL: 'http://shirts4mike.com/shirt.php?id=105',
    Date: 'September 23rd 2016, 12:28:49 am' 
},{ 
    Title: 'Mike the Frog Shirt, Yellow',
    Price: '$25',
    ImageURL: 'img/shirts/shirt-105.jpg',
    URL: 'http://shirts4mike.com/shirt.php?id=105',
    Date: 'September 23rd 2016, 12:28:50 am' 
}];

var tshirtJson = JSON.stringify(tshirtArray);

var fields = ['Title', 'Price', 'ImageURL', 'URL', 'Date'];

var csv = json2csv({ data: tshirtJson, fields: fields });

console.log(csv);

fs.writeFile('./data/file.csv', csv, {overwrite: true}, function(err) {
    if (err) throw err;
    console.log('file saved');
});
 };

convertJson2Csv();
```

Answer (score 1):

Your data object has lowercase keys. Your `fields` array has not.

```
var fields = ['Title', 'Price', 'ImageURl', 'URL', 'Date'];
```

JavaScript is case-sensitive. The field names must match the object keys.

Comment: Hey I updated the code in the question, still not working for some reason?

Answer (score 1):

Probably it cannot match the fields with the object properties.
I see on the tshirtArray objects you have an 'img' property and in the fields is 'imageURl'.

Try to change the object to:

```
var tshirtArray = [ { 'Price': '$20',
'ImageURl': 'img/shirts/shirt-107.jpg',
'Title': 'Logo Shirt, Teal',
'URL': 'http://shirts4mike.com/shirt.php?id=105',
'Date': 'September 22nd 2016, 11:17:48 pm' },
 ...
];
```

you can also make the titles pretty using passing the fieldnames:

https://github.com/zemirco/json2csv#example-4

Comment: Hey I updated the code in the question, still not working for some reason?

Comment: @bloppit try to remove the json.stringify and pass the json object tshirtArray directly to the json2csv function.

Comment: Dang, yes you're right. Though that doesn't make sense. 

I tried passing in the tshirtArray with the properties like this `'Title'` AND like this `Title`. Am I right in thinking this is strange seeing as JSON requires property keys to have quotes?

Comment: @bloppit I guess the problem is that json.stringify transforms the whole object in a JSON string, and not just quoting the object properties. 

[good examples here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/stringify)

    JSON.stringify({ x: 5 });            // '{"x":5}'